# Simplifying/Migrating Source Code method to Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, migration

I have been attempting to convert this source code to be conventionally formatted using Java 8. I have been following a few conversion guides but haven't been able to get any solutions working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the source code:

```
private List<ResponseVo> populateResponse(String userId, String type) {

    List<Wrapper> recordsList = logRepo.getEntities(type, userId);
    List<ResponseVo> responseVoList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (null != userId) {
        for (Wrapper record : recordsList) {
            if (record.getSortKey().contains(userId)) {
                ResponseVo responseVo = buildResultsResponse(record);
                responseVoList.add(responseVo);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (Wrapper record : recordsList) {
            ResponseVo testLogResponseVo = buildResultsResponse(record);
            responseVoList.add(responseVo);
        }
    }
    return responseVoList;
}
```

I have attempted using the Collectors class and Stream mapping, but am having no luck. It looked something like this:

```
            recordsList.stream()
                .filter(record -> record.getSortKey().contains(userId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: where is object for testLogResponseVo? what are you trying to do here exactly? when record contains userid you are adding it to new list but in else case also adding to same list why ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to provide the alternative response object for the case when `userId` is `null`. For that, you need to use the same conditional logic (it's not a task for streams).

In the stream, you need to transform each `Wrapper` object the matches the predicate to your target type. Which can be done using [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) operation.

```
private List<ResponseVo> populateResponse(String userId, String type) {
    
    if (userId == null) {
        return Collections.singletonList(buildResultsResponse(record));
    }
    
    return logRepo.getEntities(type, userId).stream()
        .filter(record -> record.getSortKey().contains(userId)) // Stream<Wrapper>
        .map(record -> buildResultsResponse(record))            // Stream<ResponseVo>
        .toList();                                              // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a single chain of calls starting with the `Optional` wrapper around the `userId`.

```
final List<ResponseVo> responseVoList = Optional
    .ofNullable(userId)                                // nullable userId
    .map(id -> recordsList.stream()                    // if non-null
            .filter(r -> r.getSortKey().contains(id))) // ... filter some out
    .orElseGet(recordsList::stream)                    // or else use all
    .map(this::buildResultsResponse)                   // build the response
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                     // pack as a List
```